# Basic shell scripting expr command not working

Tags: shell

I'm trying a very simple example of expr command to add a number to a variable. However, everytime I print it this is what I get :

Code :

MY=1

MY= `expr $MY+1`

// for some reason when i'm putting both the back ticks here, they disappear.

echo $MY

Output:

1+1

Why doesn't the output come as 2 in this case ? I've made sure those are back ticks and the spacing is right.

Also, when I use print instead of echo, it shows print doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add space to around `+`. Like this:

```
MY=`expr $MY + 1`
```

Because if you missed the space `$MY+1`, the shell will consider it as a string `"1+1"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked ! 
Also, I just realized if I don't put #!/bin/bash at the start for it to realize it is a script, it still works. 

Any idea why that happens ?

Comment: It always works. If you don't put `"#!/bin/bash"` at the start, the program will use the 'default' shell in your machine. Maybe the default shell is `"/bin/sh"`. Putting `"#!/bin/bash"` will the your shell use correct `bash` instead of the default